# seaborn no dibuja - anaconda ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, seaborn

Me encuentro retomando mi aprendizaje de estadística con python y se me esta generando un mensaje de precaución pero no se me esta mostrando un pequeño histograma que estoy realizando, el siguiente es el codigo.

```
import seaborn as sns


ax = sns.distplot(datos.Altura, kde=False)

ax.figure.set_size_inches(12,6)
ax.set_title("Distribución de Frecuencias - Altura", fontsize = 18)
ax.set_xlabel("Metros")
```

No obstante importe la libreria de matplotlib y con este elemento si me permitio realizar el pequeño histograma, quisiera consultar porqué motivo a otras personas si se les gráfica automática con el ejemplo anterior y cual es la mejor práctica.

Comment: El warning debe ser porque la función está marcada como `deprecated`. Y sobre el proque no se muestra pues no se mucho de seaborn, pero acaso no existe un método `show` como en matplotlib?

Comment: Me indicaron que lo que sucedia es que en google collab permitia la ejecución del código y ejecutaba el comando anterior, pero que por ejemplo en anaconda utilizando jupyter notebook se debia utilizar el comando %matplotlib inline o importar efectivamente matplotlib as plt para realizar plt.show. Pero iniciando uno queda con esas dudas.